# For single-hung windows with a spiral balance system , what is the standard areas one should weather strip?

Tags: windows, weatherstripping

I wish to weather strip my windows. Here are a few photos of the window.

[image]
[image]
[image]

This window has a spiral balance system as seen here

[image]

I have looked at a few videos on how to weather strip this type of window and I'm not seeing a consistent pattern.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3KoWG1kV1nc

This video for example removes the lower sash and then weather strips around the lower and upper sashes, but they attach the weather stripping to the stiles of the sashes and the bottom rail.

By contrast, this second video appears to attach the weather stripping to the side jambs and the sill.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sAPv9wdrNuo

I'm confused whether it is more appropriate to attach the strips to the window or the frame. What are the pros and cons of either? Is one more standard?

Edits:

Gap size between the frame and the window is 13/16th in (2.064 cm)

Here's a few shots of the inner weatherstripping that came with the window.

Top of lower sash

[image]

Left side of sash

[image]

Right side of sash

[image]

Upper right corner of lower sash

[image]

Sash measurements are

- Width: 30 + 15/16 in = 78.58 cm
- Height:  34 + 7/16 in = 87.47 cm

[image]

[image]

From what I can tell, most of the air seems to be coming from the area by the balance system. I can actively feel air coming through there.

By contrast, the bottom of the lower sash doesn't let any air in but I think adding some insulation to the bottom of the frame might help.

Comment: The balance system consists of long coil springs inside the silver tubes visible in your first picture. Doesn't matter much to your question, but it's probably a handy bit of info to know.

Comment: Also, your window already has weather strip built in, see the red arrows in [this image](https://imgur.com/a/XzERjo3). There should also be weather stripping on the horizontal parts of the sashes where they meet the window frame and where the sashes meet in the middle. Are you getting air leaks despite this weather strip?  What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @FreeMan yes exactly. Air leeks despite existing weather stripping coming up from the part where the balance system is, i.e. the silver metal rods. I wish to plug these

Comment: It appears that your windows will tilt to open so they can be cleaned. You may want to tilt one open and take a look at the condition of the factory installed weather stripping and to see if it can be replaced and/or if there's actually room to add any stick on weather stripping. If you're not sure, a clear, focused picture of the side of the sash, maybe with a tape measure/ruler, edited into the question may give someone an idea of how to better help.

Comment: @FreeMan updated the question with some of the information you mentioned. Let me know if more would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Which kind of wether striping will depend on you particular situation, like the gap size.

Adhesive Tapes

one of the most popular types of weatherstripping on the market. Best for use on window jambs, and window sashes. Downside: they tend to wear out and need to be replaced every two years.

Tubular type

are mostly used for large gap

V-Strips

Best when placed inside the tracks of sliding windows

Comment: hi, thanks for answering. if possible, would you mind clarifying what is a gap size? thanks so much!

Comment: Gap (space) between windows and the frame

Comment: Cool! Useful to know. Thanks! I added the gap size. Is there any other information that would be useful to know? Happy to provide it.

Comment: @StanShunpike with that gap size (not sure it is that much) you should try the Tubular type,  if you liked my answer , you can reward me to show it

Comment: It might help, Ruskes, if you could show what groove or large gaps there are in the OP's window that he might be able to use to install those types of insulation in. I'm not seeing anything in particular - maybe you've seen something I've missed.

Comment: V-strip may be simplest to install. Cheap , easy, and it works, though I've had problems with the adhesive giving up after a few years.